# Ruby enumerable - find up to n occurrences of matching element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array:

```
arr = [1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 5]
```

I want an array containing the first three odd elements.

I know I could do this:

```
arr.select(&:odd?).take(3)
```

but I want to avoid iterating through the whole array, and instead return once I've found the third match.

I came up with the following solution, which I believe does what I want:

```
my_arr.each_with_object([]) do |el, memo| 
  memo << el if el.odd?; break memo if memo.size == 3 
end
```

But is there a more simple/idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [lazy enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator/Lazy.html) with [Enumerable#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy):

```
arr.lazy.select(&:odd?).take(3).force
# => [1, 3, 5]
```

`force` is used to force the lazy enumerator to evaluate. Or, you could use `first` as it's eager:

```
arr.lazy.select(&:odd?).first(3)
# => [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: I confirmed that `force` works, but I cannot find the documentation except the one in [ruby lang](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/Enumerator=3a=3aLazy/i/force.html). Do you know why it is not in the documentation in RDoc? Is it because it is only an alias of `to_a`?

Comment: FYI - You could use ` arr.lazy.select(&:odd?).first(3)` and avoid the `force` - `take` is lazy while `first` isn't.

Comment: @sawa I can't find it either. If you do find it, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. As always, the doc seems incomplete. But how did you come to know this?

Comment: `Enumerator::Lazy#force` is an alias for `to_a` which comes from `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 5):

**Code and example**

```
arr.take_while.with_object([]) do |e,a|
  a << e if e.odd?
  a.size < 3
end
  #=> [1, 3, 5]
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'fruity'

def compare_em(arr, m)
  compare(
    lazy:       -> { arr.lazy.select(&:odd?).take(m).force },
    take_while: -> { arr.take_while.with_object([]) { |e,a|
                       a << e if e.odd?; a.size < m } }
  )
end

n = 1e6
arr = (1..n).to_a.shuffle
```

Obtain the first 1,000 odd elements:

```
compare_em(arr, 1e3)
  # Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
  # take_while is faster than lazy by 2x ± 1.0
```

Obtain the first 10,000 odd elements:

```
compare_em(arr, 1e4)
  # Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
  # take_while is faster than lazy by 2x ± 1.0
```

Obtain the first 100,000 odd elements:

```
compare_em(arr, 1e5)
  # Running each test once. Test will take about 3 seconds.
  # take_while is faster than lazy by 2x ± 0.1
```

I'm surprised `lazy` did quite well, as it is often much slower, relatively, in benchmarks.